# Why are my django modelformsets being prepopulated after user uploads data?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So, I have a django modelformset for allowing the user to upload multiple listings on a fake ecommerce site. When the user first accesses the "upload page" the forms are clear and there's no problem. After the user uploads some items, though, it seems like django is prepopulating the forms with the information the user submitted earlier. I don't want this, and I have no clue how to prevent it. Here is the forms.py:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "product_name",
            "product_description",
            "product_price",
        ]

class ProductImageModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = [
            "product_image",
        ]


ProductModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    Product,
    fields=(
        "product_name",
        "product_description",
        "product_price",
    ),
    extra=3,
)


ProductImageModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(
    ProductImage,
    fields=(
        "product_image",
    ),
    extra=3,
)
```

and here's the view that handles it:

```
@login_required
def product_upload_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product_form_set = ProductModelFormSet(request.POST)
        product_image_form_set = ProductImageModelFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if (product_form_set.is_valid() and product_image_form_set.is_valid()):
            for obj, obj_image in zip(product_form_set.save(commit=False), product_image_form_set.save(commit=False)):
                obj.product_seller = request.user
                obj.product_pub_date = timezone.now()
                obj.product_image = obj_image
                obj_image.save()
                obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("somewhere/else/")
                

    product_form_set = ProductModelFormSet()
    product_image_form_set = ProductImageModelFormSet()
    return render(request, "products/upload.html", {
        "product_form_set": product_form_set,
        "product_image_form_set": product_image_form_set,
    })
```

Now, I don't know if I'm even explaining my problem right because I can't seem to find an answer online but I'm sure other people have had the same issue. Basically, the formset is entirely empty when the user first tries to upload something and all is well. Then, after they upload and are redirected to another page, if they try to upload again, the forms are prepopulated with data from the first of the previous formset, and it seems to just be appending an entirely new formset to the end. I just want a brand new, fresh formset like you can do with all the regular forms (including model forms). Am I missing something? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you pressing `back` to go back to the upload page or are you clicking the link to the upload page after you are redirected?

Comment: I'm pressing the link to get to the upload page

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong. The docs are in my opinion very unclear on this but this seems to be the intended functionality of model form sets. It will create a modelform for each model you have in your database and add extra empty forms if specified (extra=3 will add 3 empty forms at the bottom of the formset). I can only imagine the intended use case is for something like inventory management to be able to edit lots of objects at the same time. this is exemplified by the fact you can add a parameter can_delete which if set to True will add a checkbox to each form so you can delete them.

Comment: Just be wary if you decide to keep the modelformset, if one user creates something using the form that the next user on the site who goes to that page will see all products in their forms  that previous user(s) have created.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe little hacky, but if you want to reset the *ModelFormset* after submitting form, just render page after submit with empty *FormSet* like this:

```
return render(request, "your_template.html", {"formset": YourFormset(queryset=YourModel.objects.none(), initial=[{
            "some_attr": "some_value", "some_attr2": "some_value2"
            }])}
```

If you set empty *queryset*, there is no data to show. I even set some initial data to forms using *initial* parameter.